# pandas DataFrame pivot with sort

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a problem presenting data in the required way. My dataframe is formatted and then sorted by 'Site ID'. I need to present the data by Site ID with all date instances grouped alongside.

I'm 90% there in terms of how I want it to look using pivot_table

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Site Ref','Site Name', 'Date'])
```

however the date column is not sorted. 
(The tiny example output appears sorted however the ****Thu Jan 11 2018 10:43:20 entry**** illustrates my issue on large data sets)

I cannot figure out how to present it like below but also with the dates sorted per site ID

Any help is gratefully accepted

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{'Site Ref': '1234567', 'Site Name': 'Building A', 'Date': 'Mon Jan 08 2018 10:43:20', 'Duration': 120}, {'Site Ref': '1245678', 'Site Name':'Building B', 'Date': 'Mon Jan 08 2018 10:43:20', 'Duration': 120}, {'Site Ref': '1245678', 'Site Name':'Building B', 'Date': 'Tue Jan 09 2018 10:43:20', 'Duration': 70}, {'Site Ref': '1245678', 'Site Name':'Building B', 'Date': 'Wed Jan 10 2018 10:43:20', 'Duration': 120}, {'Site Ref': '1212345', 'Site Name':'Building C', 'Date': 'Fri Jan 12 2018 10:43:20', 'Duration': 100}, {'Site Ref': '1123456', 'Site Name':'Building D', 'Date': 'Thu Jan 11 2018 10:43:20', 'Duration': 80}, {'Site Ref': '1123456', 'Site Name':'Building D', 'Date': 'Fri Jan 12 2018 12:22:20', 'Duration': 80}, {'Site Ref': '1123456', 'Site Name':'Building D', 'Date': 'Mon Jan 15 2018 11:43:20', 'Duration': 90}, {'Site Ref': '1123456', 'Site Name':'Building D', 'Date': 'Wed Jan 17 2018 10:43:20', 'Duration': 220}])

df = DataFrame(df, columns=['Site Ref', 'Site Name', 'Date', 'Duration'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['Site Ref'])
df

    Site Ref    Site Name   Date                        Duration
5   1123456     Building D  Thu Jan 11 2018 10:43:20    80
6   1123456     Building D  Fri Jan 12 2018 12:22:20    80
7   1123456     Building D  Mon Jan 15 2018 11:43:20    90
8   1123456     Building D  Wed Jan 17 2018 10:43:20    220
4   1212345     Building C  Fri Jan 12 2018 10:43:20    100
0   1234567     Building A  Mon Jan 08 2018 10:43:20    120
1   1245678     Building B  Mon Jan 08 2018 10:43:20    120
2   1245678     Building B  Tue Jan 09 2018 10:43:20    70
3   1245678     Building B  Wed Jan 10 2018 10:43:20    120

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Site Ref','Site Name', 'Date'])
df_pivot

Site Ref    Site Name   Date    
1123456     Building D  Fri Jan 12 2018 12:22:20    80
                        Mon Jan 15 2018 11:43:20    90
                        ****Thu Jan 11 2018 10:43:20    80****
                        Wed Jan 17 2018 10:43:20    220
1212345     Building C  Fri Jan 12 2018 10:43:20    100
1234567     Building A  Mon Jan 08 2018 10:43:20    120
1245678     Building B  Mon Jan 08 2018 10:43:20    120
                        Tue Jan 09 2018 10:43:20    70
                        Wed Jan 10 2018 10:43:20    120
```

Comment: It's sorted lexicographically, because `date` has `object` (string) dtype...

Comment: Thankyou MaxU, this worked perfectly. I had filtered the dataset up to this point using .dt boolean operations but had completely overlooked using the datetime dtype to sort on! Forest for the trees, Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

It's sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), because `Date` has object (string) dtype

Workaround - add a new column of `datetime` dtype, use it before `Date` in the `pivot_table` and drop it afterwards:

```
In [74]: (df.assign(x=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
            .pivot_table(df, index=['Site Ref','Site Name', 'x', 'Date'])
            .reset_index(level='x', drop=True))
Out[74]:
                                              Duration
Site Ref Site Name  Date
1123456  Building D Thu Jan 11 2018 10:43:20        80
                    Fri Jan 12 2018 12:22:20        80
                    Mon Jan 15 2018 11:43:20        90
                    Wed Jan 17 2018 10:43:20       220
1212345  Building C Fri Jan 12 2018 10:43:20       100
1234567  Building A Mon Jan 08 2018 10:43:20       120
1245678  Building B Mon Jan 08 2018 10:43:20       120
                    Tue Jan 09 2018 10:43:20        70
                    Wed Jan 10 2018 10:43:20       120
```

Comment: Perhaps we can use `sort=False` in groupby

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your dates to datetime values rather than strings. Something like the following would work on your current pivot table:

```
df_pivot.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_pivot['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_pivot['Date'])
df_pivot.sort_values(by=['Site Ref', 'Date'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the values by Site Ref, groupby mean using `sort = False` i.e

```
df.sort_values('Site Ref').groupby(['Site Ref','Site Name','Date'],sort=False).mean()

                                            Duration
Site Ref Site Name  Date                              
1123456  Building D Thu Jan 11 2018 10:43:20        80
                    Fri Jan 12 2018 12:22:20        80
                    Mon Jan 15 2018 11:43:20        90
                    Wed Jan 17 2018 10:43:20       220
1212345  Building C Fri Jan 12 2018 10:43:20       100
1234567  Building A Mon Jan 08 2018 10:43:20       120
1245678  Building B Mon Jan 08 2018 10:43:20       120
                    Tue Jan 09 2018 10:43:20        70
                    Wed Jan 10 2018 10:43:20       120
```